# API request (Access-Control-Allow-Origin error)

Tags: javascript, php, json, fetch-api

The person responsible for API requests is gone for the week, so nothing can be done on server side.

```
fetch("https://url.com/api/login/", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        // 'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        username: "test@mail.com",
        password: "123"
    })
}).then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
}).then(function (myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
});
```

It works on Postman, but as I heard, Postman doesn't follow the same security as browsers, therefore this isn't an issue for Postman. But I doubt this is the case, as the authors php-solution works fine.

This is an example of php-solution that works:

```
function login($username, $password) {
    $curl = curl_init(); curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://url.com/api/login/",
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "username=".$username."&password=".$password,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $authdata = json_decode($response);
    if ($authdata -> success) {
        //success
        return true;
    } else {
        //fail
        return false;
    }
}
```

What's missing in my code? How can I make it work like the PHP solution? (Have no experience in PHP).

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

What worked on Postman:

- Raw JSON format in Body.
- Adding values as `Key` and `Value` in `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this error you can do 3 things:

1. Add your origin server side.
2. Run your javascript on the same domain.
3. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome) answer for disabling same origin policy in chrome. This will allow you to test your code until the guy responsible for de API returns.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will check those options shortly. Btw, is my solution correct, meaning it's server side issue / or have to be on same domain?

Comment: Well, the browser blocks the request because the domain of the API is different then the domain your javascript runs on. When adding the Allow Origin line on the server. The server tells the browser (in the response headers) to Allow your javascript domain. So yes, that's server side.